How to make this chess piece's necklace?

Hi, I'm trying to model this chess piece following this concept art to practice modeling. I have modeled the body of the King. This is what I have done so far:

I tried to make this "necklace" as a separate mesh but it looked ugly. Any ideas or hints on how to approach this? Thanks

Hello, do you want it to be part of the same mesh or do you want it to be a separate mesh?

Either is fine for me. From what I can see from the concept, it seems like they are from the same mesh

if this is the same mesh, maybe use the Knife Project tool to project the shape onto the cylinder, then extrude the faces?

You could crate a mesh that draws the pattern, remove the faces with X (Delete) > Only Faces, put it in front of your cylinder, select the cylinder, switch to Edit mode, CtrlRMB on the pattern object and Mesh > Knife Project:

It leaves these new edges on the surface of the cylinder:

Extrude and model the pattern:


I don't know there is a "Knife Project" tool. Definitely will try out this method. Thanks.
